# why when i try having my player teleport to the object it says this?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My error is

> CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'UnityEngine.Vector3'

Code:

```
{
    GameObject snowball = GameObject.Find("LaunchSlingshotProjectile").GetComponent<SnowballThrowable>().projectilePrefab;
    GorillaLocomotion.Player.Instance.transform.position = snowball;
}
```

I tried adding it to a variable but it didn't do anything

Comment: `snowball.transform.position`

Comment: Because a `GameObject` is not a `Vector3` and there is no direct conversion between those ...

Answer (score 0):

```
GameObject snowball = GameObject.Find("LaunchSlingshotProjectile")
```

Now snowball is a GameObject;

```
SnowballThrowable sbthrowable = snowball.GetComponent<SnowballThrowable>();
```

sbthrowable is a Component.

```
GameObject tile = sbthrowable.projectilePrefab;
```

tile is a GameObject variable which defined by yourself.

```
Vector3 pos = tile.transform.position;
```

The pos variable's type is Vector3, **Only variables of the same type can be assigned**.

```
GorillaLocomotion.Player.Instance.transform.position = pos;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
GorillaLocomotion.Player.Instance.transform.position = GameObject.Find("LaunchSlingshotProjectile").GetComponent<SnowballThrowable>().projectilePrefab.transform.position;
```

---

Your error is that you are trying to set a position

```
GorillaLocomotion.Player.Instance.transform.position = ...
```

which is a Vector3, and you are passing a GameObject for it, so the compiler doesn't understand.

---

A tip would be storing whatever `GameObject.Find("LaunchSlingshotProjectile")` is in a variable so that you don't perform this operation all the time, since Find is slow.